# How to VBA Code To Create A Search Folder That Looks For Message Class?

Tags: vba, outlook

we have a Document Management System that when an email is sent or recieved and is filed it gets given a Message class that contains `EMS`, I want a code that will create a search folder that will search "Sent Items" for a message class that contains `EMS`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [AdvancedSearch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb219884.aspx) method. The `AdvancedSearch` method and related features in the Outlook object model do not create a Search Folder that will appear in the Outlook user interface. However, you can use the `Save` method of the `Search` object that is returned to create a Search Folder that will appear in the Search Folders list in the Outlook user interface.